# What's the term for the combat used in games like Ghost of Tsushima and Spider-Man?

Tags: terminology, genre-identification

Is there a term for the combat mode used in games like *Ghost of Tsushima* and *Spider-Man*? Specifically, where attacks are telegraphed, and choosing and timing your response are important. These games also share in common the feature of expanding your attack repertoire as enemies become stronger or use new attack methods, and chaining multiple attacks to power up for higher power attacks.

Comment: My guess would be 'souls-like' style combat. Where you must learn each enemies attack patterns. Not sure if that's the first of this style though.

Comment: Is it similar to or exactly like what the Assassin's Creed series has done since II (if I'm not mistaken?)?

Comment: More since the soft reboot of Origins. Pretty sure until 4 it was always the parry based combat. But yeah, like Neon, I would say its a combat style that was introduced in souls. A combat where going all out and just mashing attack will most likely get you killed. But I dont think there is an actual name for it.

Comment: I personally don't think the combat of Dark Souls has much in common with the combat of Spider-Man. I think the early Assassin's Creed combat is more similar, but the earliest game I remember which feels the same way was Batman: Arkham Asylum.

Comment: If anything this type of combat was if not introduced popularized by the Batman: Arkam Asylum game. There it was dubbed "Freeflow". Other than that I don't really think it has much of a specific name.